# On the P&T form add-on you have to use a message field is there a way round this?

Tags: plugins, emails, plugin-contactform

Unless I am misunderstanding the docs for the [P&T form](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm/tree/master/contactform), it says you have to include the message field, if some forms don't have a message field is the only way to not show this hide it with CSS?

Just wondered what other people are doing for forms - I am also looking at the Sprout form add-ons.

Comment: I have submitted a pull request for the P&T form to make the message field not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add a hidden input called "messages" set to "" (or if that doesn't work ".")?

What's the use case for wanted to send a contact email with a message body?

Comment: Hi Brad, I still want to send content in to the email message body its just that content would be from the additional fields. Maybe thats where I am misunderstanding. I use a form field like: `<input id="phone" type="text" name="message[Phone]" value="">` does that count as having content in the message field?

Comment: Hi Brad, yes sorry I have misunderstood what was meant my the message field. Adding `<input id="phone" type="text" name="message[Phone]" value="">` counts as having content in the message field. Sorry.